# Google Sheets - Auto Find & Replace

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a large spreadsheet that imports basketball statistics from various websites throughout the day and then index-matches them in other tables. My problem is that some websites use a name like "Lou Williams," while others use "Louis Williams." Each time I update one of the tabs with new data, I have to manually correct all the discrepancies between names. Is there a way to write a script that auto corrects the 10-12 names that I am constantly having to fix? I'd love to find some way to do this that is easier than doing a "Find & Replace" 10 different times.

I'd also love if these "spell checks" would happen only on 3 specific tabs, but would also be ok if it happened across the entire worksheet.

I've done some research for a solution but I'm so new to scripting that it's hard to for me to translate other people's code.

Here is a (current) list of the names I frequently have to correct
INCORRECT               CORRECT
Louis Williams          Lou Williams
Kelly Oubre             Kelly Oubre Jr.
Patrick Mills           Patty Mills
James Ennis             James Ennis III
Alex Abrines            Álex Abrines
Guillermo Hernangomez   Guillermo Hernangómez
Ishmael Smith           Ish Smith
Sergio Rodriguez        Sergio Rodríguez
Larry Nance             Larry Nance Jr
Luc Mbah a Moute        Luc Richard Mbah a Moute
Juan Hernangomez        Juancho Hernangómez
Glenn Robinson          Glenn Robinson III

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways to do this, but this uses a 'Name List' sheet with correct and incorrect names. Run 'fix' from the custom menu and column A names will change the names to the correct ones. Here is the code and a sample spreadsheet you can copy and run.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Correct Names', [ 
      { name: 'Fix', functionName: 'changeNames' },
      ]);  
 }
function changeNames() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets() //get all sheets
  var numSheets=allSheets.length
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Name List")//get the list on names to change. 
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var rng= s.getRange(2, 1, lr, 2).getValues()
  for(var k=0;k<numSheets;k++){//loop through sheets 
   var s1=ss.getSheets()[k]
   var test =s1.getSheetName()
    if (s1.getSheetName()== "RG" || s1.getSheetName()=="NF" ||   s1.getSheetName()=="SWISH"){ //Sheets to process. '||' is OR
   var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
   var rng1=s1.getRange(2, 1, lr1, 1).getValues()// Assumes names start on eow 2 Column A. Adjust as needed 
  for(i=0;i<rng1.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<rng.length;j++){ 
      if(rng1[i][0]==rng[j][1]){//if incorrect names match
        rng1[i][0]=rng[j][0] //replace incorrect name with correct name
      }}}
  s1.getRange(2,1, lr1, 1).setValues(rng1)//replace names
   }}}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16DPTDTCqzhYTGVmUpb1wlNFI8ZK7xoJNZvobufXapvg/edit?usp=sharing

Changed to only run certain sheets.

Comment: This works great! I wonder if there is one small modification that could be made. My spreadsheet is quite large with a lot of data and tabs, so it takes a while to run. Is it possible to limit it to only 3 tabs labeled "RG," "NF," and "SWISH."

Comment: This is amazing and runs so much faster! Thank you so much!

Comment: All of the sheets have the names in the first column except for one sheet, which has names in the 2nd column. I've tried modifying the 4th number in "getRange" to be "2," but that isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: I changed the shared spreadsheet to handle names of one sheet in column B. I used 'SWISH' in the example. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm not able to see the script in the shared spreadsheet. Are you able to share?

Comment: Try it now and it should let you. Or make a copy.

Comment: I can see it now, but for some reason the updated script isn't working. I tried it within my spreadsheet as well as in your document and it's not correcting the names in the 2nd column.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. It only looks for names to be in column B on the 'SWISH' sheet. Change the code for other sheets.

Comment: For some reason, the script has stopped working for me. I've adjusted it to include a bunch more tabs, but now I'm getting the error:
The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 19, file "mlbSpellCheck") I've looked through it and can't find any reason why I'm getting this error.

I've made a copy of the spreadsheet so feel free to make whatever edits you like.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lhvu_ZsgruOG6uVUtLu5kfyyaOkbBgbXAWxB77UyTnI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your range error is caused by sheets FG_B and FG_P. They are completely empty to there is no last row of data causing the range error. I entered 'test' in both sheets and it ran fine. Also, you can't have two onOpens. Only one of your menu items is being built. Combine the code into one. This thread is getting long. If you have more questions email me at ednelson@sbcgolbal.net.